# Right clicking a file, Can't delete files/folders, no option to delete.

Tags: files, delete

I have some files and folders that I can't delete. I click menu -> right click and the delete option is not available.

I can delete by using the terminal, but I'd prefer to do it from the GUI.

It's something to do with permissions, can someone help?

Comment: What files and folders won't give you the option to delete them?

Answer (score 8):

Make the current user owns everything inside the folder,itself as well as the parent folder.

```
chown $USER -R /desired.folder
```

Comment: ok, but what about the rest the files in system. I can't delete anything in desktop, home folder, even on partitons

Comment: some one messed up ur permessions i think you need some one advanced.... i recommend booting live medium again and repairing ur existing installation

Comment: found it in termian - sudo chmod +s /usr/bin/avrdude and ls -al /usr/bin/avrdude thats all. I even cant remeber from when i can't use delete cut and move to option ...

Comment: you have to run that command in terminal

just ur home directory and other partition should have all access dont mess with other direcotry  partitions

Comment: i run it in right directory;/

Comment: @Matt run "sudo chown <youruser> -R ~" (replace <youruser> with you user name).

Comment: mateusz@acer:~$ sudo chown mateusz -R ~
chown: cannot access `/home/mateusz/.gvfs': Permission denied

Comment: @Matt The `.gvfs` error shouldn't matter. That's a dynamic mount folder. It's unlikely to be one of the files/folders you want to delete, and it's normal that even `root` cannot modify it.

Comment: what if another user logins algo into the system ? would they also be able to delete/change the files ?

Answer (score 1):

For those particular cases I use nautilus as root:
Press Alt-F2 and type:

> gksu nautilus

Then proceed with caution, you may seriously damage your system.

Comment: Hmm... good solution but why i can edit files on ubuntu partition but i cant do in on the rest ntfs partition;/. Is is possible repair it?

Comment: Matt, as root you're supposed to do everything. However, you can't change owner or permissions on ntfs partitions, I had a similar problem and fixed it adding my user to the group that owned the ntfs file system...

Comment: hell yeah! i had turned off write option in NTFS manager... lol!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove file and folder from terminal you can use

```
rm <filename>
```

delete folder

```
rm -rf <foldername>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to delete an NVIDIA DSW user's guide from the desktop at least 20 times but it re-appeared after restart or boot.  None of the suggestions above helped, because I could delete the file.  I finally did a "find" for the file and a copy was in /usr/share/oem-config-dsw/ qlong with a script that kept re-installing it to the desktop.  Removing the file and script in this folder fixed the problem.

Comment: This is a specific file. We don't know what files and folders OP is talking about.

Comment: This is a specific file. We don't know what files and folders OP is talking about.

Answer (score -1):

change the name of the folder that contains those files or folders.

for example: The_name_of_the_root_folder_that_contains_the_not_manageable_files
change it to 1 or Name