# How can I change the owner of a folder?

Tags: permissions, root

I am an emigrant from Windows but I am having a serious problem which is changing the **Root permission**.

I tried to changed the owner by doing right click and change the permission but it's not working.

Can any one help me to move these folder?

Comment: Hello and welcome! I think what you are looking for may be the answers to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/106272/58950)

Comment: Can you provide more information about exactly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by using the `chown` command.

Usage: `chown -R $user $directory`

For example, if you wanted to change the permission of folder you created as root named "example" inside your home directory, you would first obtain root privileges by typing `su`, and then run `chown -R ousman /home/ousman/example`, assuming your username is "ousman". The "-R" stands for "recursive", so that the owner of the files inside the directory changes as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few good ways to do this:

Graphical method:

press alt+f2 or open a new terminal window and type:

```
gksu nautilus
```

"browse to and right click on the folder you would like to modify. Then, select "Properties" from the context menu. You can now select the user or group that you would like to be the "Owner" of the folder as well as the permissions you would like to grant them. Finally, press "Apply Permissions to Enclosed Files" to apply the changes recursively.

Though it seems this does not always work for some operations in a deep folder tree. If it does not work use the appropriate terminal command."

-andrewsomething

Geeky way:
enter the following into the terminal (replacing username and directorypath with your username and the path of the folder you want to modify):

```
sudo chown -R username directorypath
```

If you are not shure what your username is, (case sensitive!) see the top of the terminal window, it should be something like:

```
Name@computername
```

A simple way to paste the directory path is to pull it into the terminal window